# How to convert a column to row.names from a tibble

Tags: r, tibble, r-rownames

This is a sample (normally it is 15 x 17) from my dataset `entrepreneur` imported from Excel with `read_excel`:

```
structure(list(Factors = c("Competition", "Cultural Support", "Financing", "High Growth", "Human Capital"), `Baden-Württemberg` = c("0.71", "0.66", "0.81", "0.62", "0.46"), Bayern =c("0.67", "0.66", "0.83", "0.77", "0.49"), Berlin = c("1.00", "0.56", "0.90", "0.82", "0.79"), Brandenburg = c("1.00", "0.55", "0.64", "1.00", "0.77")), row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

or in this format:

```
EntrepreneurIndex
# A tibble: 5 x 5
  Factors          `Baden-Württemberg` Bayern Berlin Brandenburg
  <chr>            <chr>               <chr>  <chr>  <chr>      
1 Competition      0.71                0.67   1.00   1.00       
2 Cultural Support 0.66                0.66   0.56   0.55       
3 Financing        0.81                0.83   0.90   0.64       
4 High Growth      0.62                0.77   0.82   1.00       
5 Human Capital    0.46                0.49   0.79   0.77
```

The first column as you can see is consisting of my factor variables. I would like to have the first column be transferred to rownames. I have used codes like

```
rownames(entrepreneur)  <- entrepreneur[,1]
```

, which led to the error message error in `` `.rowNamesDF<-`(x, value = value) : non-valid 'row.names' length Zusätzlich: Warnmeldung: Setting row names on a tibble is deprecated. ``

I'm unfortunately new to the concept of tibbles.
I have tried transforming the data into a data frame as another post https://stackoverflow.com/a/50904626 has adviced with `as.data.frame(entrepreneur)`, but this only lead to the same error message as before.

Going to https://tibble.tidyverse.org/reference/rownames.html adviced me to use

```
column_to_rownames(entrepreneur, var = "Factors")
```

This didn't cause an error, but it didn't transform the first column to rownames.

After reading the advice and other posts, I'm now not sure whether you can or cannot transfer the first column of a tibble into a row names column. Preferably I would have the first column a rowname for further analysis (regression, etc.) if that's possible.

Comment: entrepeneur %>% column_to_rownames('Factors') works for me.

Comment: The function that you are using does exactly what it's supposed to, however if you want to save it to `entrepreneur` you need to add `entrepreneur <-`

Comment: Did you load the tidyverse package with library(tidyverse)?

Comment: Assign the output back to `entrepreneur` i.e `entrepreneur <- entrepreneur %>% column_to_rownames('Factors')`

Comment: As @RonakShah and @WietsedeVries mentioned, I didnt assign the output back to my dataset variable. After correcting for this, @deschen 's command `entrepeneur %>% column_to_rownames('Factors')` worked out successfully for me! Thanks a lot for the correction!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you can see the difference

```
> str(entrepreneur[, 1])
tibble [5 x 1] (S3: tbl_df/tbl/data.frame)
 $ Factors: chr [1:5] "Competition" "Cultural Support" "Financing" "High Growth" ...      

> str(entrepreneur[[1]])
 chr [1:5] "Competition" "Cultural Support" "Financing" "High Growth" ...
```

---

Try the code below (using `entrepreneur[[1]]` rather than `entrepreneur[,1]`)

```
> `rownames<-`(as.data.frame(entrepreneur[-1]), entrepreneur[[1]])
                 Baden-Wⁿrttemberg Bayern Berlin Brandenburg
Competition                   0.71   0.67   1.00        1.00
Cultural Support              0.66   0.66   0.56        0.55
Financing                     0.81   0.83   0.90        0.64
High Growth                   0.62   0.77   0.82        1.00
Human Capital                 0.46   0.49   0.79        0.77
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set the rownames like so:

```
rownames(entrepreneur) <- entrepreneur$Factors
```

However, if you're planning on running regressions on the data in each row, instead of setting row names, you may want to look into how to make nested tibbles--basically, tibbles where one row consists of tibbles (tibbles in tibbles!). Then you can iterate functions over those nested tibbles with `purrr::map()`, and e.g. run a regression on each line of data and keep the results all in one tibble.

You can read more about nesting tibbles here: https://tidyr.tidyverse.org/articles/nest.html

Comment: Hello, thx for the comment. As mentioned above I found another solution. I have thought about your idea before, however trying the code always gave me the error message "Setting row names on a tibble is deprecated."
Thx also for the nest literature. I might need it later in my further work!

Comment: No prob. Also the "setting rownames is deprecated" message looks like a warning, not an error. I get that message too but it puts the row names on anyway.

Comment: It's true, when I look at the data via the view command, it puts the column as row names as you say. However, the initial column is additionally still there and when I try to delete it via `entrepreneur  <- entrepreneur[,-1]` it not only deletes this column, it also deletes the row names I just created.